# Pipe and space give problem when used in regex

Tags: linux

To start, I want to say that I am a complete beginner in Linux. I try codes I find on the internet and in manuals, but sometimes even when I literally use the exact same code explained on the site or manual it still gives me an error.
For example, in the following cases I tried the commands grep and cut with different values and some worked and others failed.

```
    grep Belgie landen //this works fine
    grep -E 'B|F' landen //when I use the pipe it fails

    cut -d: -f1 landen //this works fine if the textfile has : as delimiter
    cut -d' ' -f1 landen //this fails even when text has space as a delimiter
```

In the first failed case the terminal responds with: bash: F': command not found...

In the second failed case the terminal responds with: cut: ': No such file or directory
Then it shows the whole content of the file landen.

It seems that it doesn't read ' ' as a space and | as OR.

Comment: `when I literally use the exact same code ` "How" _exactly_ do you _use_ it? Do you include all the `'` properly? Could you reproduce the problem in an online editor, like [repl](https://repl.it/languages/bash)? And [all 4 commands work for me](https://repl.it/@kamilcukrowski/SoreAmusingInterpreter#main.sh).

Comment: `man <command>` is your friend (i.e. `man grep`, `man cut`). If there's no man page, then I try using `--help` (i.e. `grep --help`, `cut --help`), but some commands don't recognize `--help`.

Comment: Could you please be as kind as to show the content of the `landen file` ? And please tell what you mean by `grep -E 'B|F landem` fails ? While regular expressions can be tricky sometimes, here your example found `Belgie` and `Firenze`.

Comment: I'm guessing you are actually on Windows, where the quoting rules are different. As stated, your problem cannot be reproduced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your actual file has Unicode quotes. If you look very closely, you can see that they're slightly more slanted than the regular ASCII apostrophe. Here is some example output:

```
$ grep -E ‘B|F’ landen
bash: F’: command not found

$ cut -f1 -d‘ ’ landen
cut: ’: No such file or directory
```

Here's how you can tell with [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net):

```
$ shellcheck myscript
In myscript line 2:
grep -E ‘B|F’ landen
        ^-- SC1110: This is a unicode quote. Delete and retype it (or quote to make literal).
            ^-- SC1110: This is a unicode quote. Delete and retype it (or quote to make literal).


In myscript line 5:
cut -d‘ ’ -f1 landen
      ^-- SC1110: This is a unicode quote. Delete and retype it (or quote to make literal).
        ^-- SC1110: This is a unicode quote. Delete and retype it (or quote to make literal).
```

And here's `cat -vE` showing something's up:

```
$ cat -vE myscript
grep Belgie landen$
grep -E M-bM-^@M-^XB|FM-bM-^@M-^Y landen$
$
cut -d: -f1 landen$
cut -dM-bM-^@M-^X M-bM-^@M-^Y -f1 landen$
```

You actual post has ASCII apostrophes which is why no one can reproduce it, but it also has invalid C++-style comments, so it's fair to assume that this is not the code you're running.